# Model data and indices for my query patterns?

Tags: mysql, sql, data-modeling

How should I model this data in MySql?

I have data that looks like this:

There are many ITEMS, some of which share a ITEMGROUP.  Each ITEM has a list of 0-10 or 20 events. Each ITEM can be in either an INPROGRESS state, or a COMPLETED state.

I'd like to query this data in two ways:

1. All ITEMS in an ITEMGROUP.  To be queried on demand.
2. One ITEM by a unique identifier, along with all the events
   associated with it. To be queried on demand.
3. All ITEMS INPROGRESS. At least once an hour.

There are 2,000,000 ITEMS per month entered.  So after a year the DB would have 24,000,000 ITEMS.

What is the best way to model my data and indices for this data and these query patterns?  What issues if any should I be on the lookout for with this data and these queries?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand you. But it is a simple schema for a relational databases. Something like this?

```
Table: Item (Id, ...)
Table: ItemGroup (Id, FK_Item, ...)
Table: ItemEvent (Id, FK_Item, ...)

SELECT Item.* 
FROM Item JOIN ItemGroup ON Item.Id = ItemGroup.FK_Item 
WHERE ItemGroup.Id = ? ...

SELECT ItemEvent.* 
FROM Item JOIN ItemEvent ON Item.Id = ItemEvent.FK_Item 
WHERE Item.Id = ? ...

SELECT Item.* 
FROM Item JOIN ItemEvent ON Item.Id = ItemEvent.FK_Item 
WHERE ItemEvent.state = 'INPROGRESS' ...
```

Primary key on `Id` and also a index on all foreign keys (`FK_...`). In this case the foreign key index `ItemEvent.FK_Item` should also include the column `ItemEvent.state`.